# Change cell border color in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2

I would like to change the border color when a user touches the cell. I have the following code in my UICollectionView but it's not working:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.user["avatar"] = self.avatars[indexPath.row]

        do {
           try self.user.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("returnToProfile", sender: user)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AvatarViewCell
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor

    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried the top-voted answer in the question that was flagged as a duplicate but it still doesn't work. `cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor` doesn't change the color.

Maybe it's an issue with how I'm defining cell?

Comment: I tried the answer in that question but it still didn't work. I think it might be an issue with how I define cell

Comment: did you try to change the content view´s border? `cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I using data source to change cell background when touching:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DateCell

        if !days.contains(Functions.tools.nextThreeWeeks().long[indexPath.row]) {
            days.append(cell.fullDate)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.72, blue:0.35, alpha:1)
        } else {
            days = days.arrayRemovingObject(cell.fullDate)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        print(days)

    }
```

Comment: That worked! I needed to change my cell definition to use `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.